# Delegate evaluate order

Tags: c#

I was trying to bind following operation on delegates: 
`2*2+2` this should give of course 6 but my example give 8

I thought that all delegates used here will not be evaluated until this linie

```
  var result = response();
```

but it works somehow other way then I was expected, I thought that under response variable delegate will be :
`EvaluateConst()() * EvaluateConst()() + EvaluateConst()()` and this way math operators shold take priority from language specification but not.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var response = Mul();
            var result = response();
        }

        public static Func<double> Add()
        {
            return () => EvaluateConst()() + EvaluateConst()();
        }

        public static Func<double> Mul()
        {
            return () => EvaluateConst()() * Add()();
        }

        public static Func<double> EvaluateConst()
        {
            return () => 2;
        }
```

Is there a way by modifying this to achieve what I want ?

Intresting is that if set breakPoint on line `return () => 2;`
debuger catch it only after finall evaluating in  `var result = response();`

Comment: You yourself are forcing an evaluation order by *defining* `Mul` to be the result of multiplying the result of `Add` by `2`. It's as if you'd written `2*(2+2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not evaluating 2 * 2 + 2. You're evaluating

```
2 * (2 + 2)
```

The fact that delegates are involved is irrelevant here - you're always evaluating them as soon as they're returned anyway. You can effectively rewrite the code as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = Mul();
}

public static double Add()
{
    return EvaluateConst() + EvaluateConst();
}

public static double Mul()
{
    return EvaluateConst() * Add();
}

public static double EvaluateConst()
{
    return 2;
}
```

First understand why *that* returns 8, then you can go back to your delegate version. This is the line that does the multiplication:

```
return () => EvaluateConst()() * Add()();
```

When you call `EvaluateConst`, that returns a delegate that, when invoked, will return 2.

When you call `Add`, that returns a delegate that, when invoked, will return 4 (by way of itself calling `EvaluateConst` and invoking the delegate, doing that twice, and adding the results together).

So your lambda expression is converted into a delegate which, when invoked, basically evaluates 2 * 4.

If you want to evaluate 2 * 2 + 2, you should think of it as this:

```
     +
  *     2
2   2
```

In other words:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var response = Add();
    var result = response();
}

public static Func<double> Add()
{
    return () => Mul()() + EvaluateConst()();
}

public static Func<double> Mul()
{
    return () => EvaluateConst()() * EvaluateConst()();
}
```

... but again, the delegate side of this is really a red herring.

Comment: Is there some why to modify this to achive what I want, or better is to rewrite it to expression tree using left and right nodes and at the end compile expression and launch it ?

Comment: @kosnkov: Well if you want 2 * 2 + 2, that should be `Add` calling `Mul`... but it's not clear why you're doing this with delegates at all.

Comment: I wished to parse string with simple math operators building operation tree. But then I need to find first nodes with * and / and then + and -. So I thought I will just build big expression and evaluate it at the end so evaluation process will use operators priority from language spec.

Comment: @kosnkov: In C#, the precedence is built into the grammar. It's still not clear what the connection is between that and what you've shown here. Does my answer actually help you? It's not clear why you expected a result of 6... does my translation into non-delegates help?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Add()()` is a function, its result has to be evaluated before the multiplication can take place.  This means that your function `Mul()` is equivalent to:

```
public static Func<double> Mul()
{
    return () => EvaluateConst()() * (EvaluateConst()() + EvaluateConst()());
}
```

which is the same as `return 2 * (2 + 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to understand why...

First you are calling `Mul`, which needs to get both operators from `EvaluateConst` and `Add`, so it calls `EvaluateConst()` returning 2, and then calls `Add` returning 4, 2 * 4 = 8.

It would be exactly the same had you not used delegates

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Mul());

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static double Add()
    {
        return EvaluateConst() + EvaluateConst();
    }

    public static double Mul()
    {
        return EvaluateConst() * Add();
    }

    public static double EvaluateConst()
    {
        return 2;
    }
```

which returns 8.