# Expression execution order

Tags: c#

Shouldn't that return 6 instead of 8 ? Doesn't it work this way that using combination of expressions it returns one big expression and this should evaluate as `2+2*2` instaed `(2+2)*2`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var response = Mul();
            var result = response.Compile().Invoke();
        }

        public static Expression<Func<double>> Add()
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(Expression.Add(EvaluateConst().Body, EvaluateConst().Body));
        }

        public static Expression<Func<double>> Mul()
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(Expression.Multiply(EvaluateConst().Body, Add().Body));
        }

        public static Expression<Func<double>> EvaluateConst()
        {
            return () => 2;
        }
```

Comment: You're essentially doing `(2)*(2+2)`.

Comment: This is pretty similar to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969676/delegate-evaluate-order)...

Comment: @petelids exacly I thought that expressions make the difference, so what is the difference between this and those question ?

Comment: Note that there is no expression for `(` or `)`.  The order of operations is specified by the expression tree itself; the grouping logic is expressed in the tree's structure.

Comment: It returns one big expression *tree*, and the nodes you've created are a hierarchy that is effectively `(2)*(2+2)` - the same as your earlier question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A return value of "8" makes sense here.

Before `Expression.Multiply` can be run, its arguments must be fully determined. So each function is run.

- The first evaluates to "2".
- The second, add, evaluates to "4"

And 2 * 4 is 8.

Answer (score 3):

No, it should not.  If it should have, it would have.  Your instructions are to multiply 2 with the results of the addition, because you pass 2 and *the results of the addition* as the operations to the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing around operators as arguments to the functions. While the compiler can see `2+2*2` and make the jump to `Add(2, Multiply(2, 2))`, expressions do not. An easy way to see this is to think (or rather, realize, since it's true) that operators are static functions, or replace your operator expressions with Method Call Expressions.

Comment: Method calls, though you would need to have actual methods to call- the suggestion is more mental than literal.